# Can this integral be calculated using Mathematica?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex, assumptions

I have the following integral:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm d\tau}{2\pi \mathrm i} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm d\tau'}{2\pi \mathrm i} \frac{\mathrm e^{-c^2(\tau - \tau')^2}}{(\tau - \mathrm i \epsilon)(\tau' - \mathrm i\epsilon')}.
$$

Here I wanted to do the $\tau'$ integral first, so I wrote the following

```
 $Assumptions = c >= 0 && c \[Element] Reals && ϵ > 0 && ϵ \[Element] Reals && δ > 0 && δ \[Element] Reals  && τ \[Element] Reals && t \[Element] Reals;

 I5 = Integrate[E^(-c^2 (τ - t)^2)/(( τ - I ϵ) (t - I δ)), {t, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

where I have denoted $\tau'$ using t. However the output turns out to be just the same expression as the input.

Next I tried to use the residue of the integrand about $ \tau' = \mathrm i\epsilon' $ (In the code below, about $ t = \mathrm i\delta $).

```
Residue[e^(-c^2 (τ - t)^2)/((τ - I ϵ) (t - I δ)), {t, I δ}]
```

Again the output turns out to be the same expression as the input.

Any suggestions how to compute the integral?

EDIT: It was pointed out in the comments that there were some mistakes in the code, so I edited the same.

Comment: e should be E and { } should be ( ) when used for grouping terms

Comment: @bills I see, thanks. Let me try that out.

Comment: @bills While the Integrate command is still giving the same, the Residue command is working properly now. Thanks.

Comment: The syntax for global assumptions is `$Assumptions = c>=0 && c \[Element] Reals && \[Epsilon] > 0 && ...`

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform thanks for the correction. However even after this correction, the Integrate is giving me the same expression.

Comment: @MichaelWilliams The syntax is still wrong. Note that I used `=` instead of `[...]`.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I see. I corrected the same. By the way, is there any way I can compute this integral?

Comment: You can calculate the real part of the integral using `Integrate[E^(-c^2 (τ - t)^2)/((τ - I ϵ) t), {t, -Infinity, Infinity}, Assumptions -> {c > 0 && ϵ > 0 && τ \[Element] Reals}, PrincipalValue -> True]`. The imaginary part is trivial to evaluate using $\mathrm{im}\left[\frac{1}{x-i\epsilon}\right]=\pi\delta(x)$.

Comment: `Residue` does not return the same expression as the input as you said.

Comment: For your reference, `Residue[Residue[
   E^(-c^2 (\[Tau] - \[Tau]p)^2)/((\[Tau] - I \[Epsilon]) (\[Tau]p - 
      I \[Epsilon]p)), {\[Tau], I \[Epsilon]}] , {\[Tau]p, 
   I \[Epsilon]p}] // Simplify` gives `E^(c^2 (\[Epsilon] - \[Epsilon]p)^2)`, which I think is very close to the result you are seeking, however I am not sure.

Answer (score 2):

C is just a normalization factor, so we set `c = 1`, make a substitution,

```
t = (x + y)/2; t1 = (x - y)/2;
Exp[-(t - t1)^2]/(t - A)/(t1 - B) // FullSimplify

Out[]= -((4 E^-y^2)/((2 B - x + y) (-2 A + x + y)))
```

then the integral with respect to one of the variables is calculated exactly

```
Integrate[-((
  4 E^-y^2)/((2 B - x + y) (-2 A + x + y))), {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]

Out[]= ConditionalExpression[(
 2 E^(-4 A^2 - 4 B^2 + 4 A x + 4 B x - 
   2 x^2) (E^(-2 B + x)^2 \[Pi] Erfi[2 A - x] + 
    E^(-2 A + x)^2 \[Pi] Erfi[2 B - x] - E^(-2 B + x)^2 Log[2 A - x] -
     E^(-2 A + x)^2 Log[2 B - x] + E^(-2 B + x)^2 Log[-2 A + x] + 
    E^(-2 A + x)^2 Log[-2 B + x]))/(A + B - x), 
 2 Im[A] != Im[x] && 2 Im[B] != Im[x] && 2 A - x \[NotElement] Reals &&
   2 B - x \[NotElement] Reals && -2 A + x \[NotElement] 
   Reals && -2 B + x \[NotElement] Reals]
```

Comment: Actually your variable substitution works for me if you let `c` stay `c`.  But I think you need a factor `1/2` in front of the integral since `dt = dy/2`.  Then don't forget to convert `x` back to the `t`'s.

Comment: @BillWatts Thank you. I think all this should be interesting to the author. But he did not answer.